# How to fix Nginx config that downloads PHP file after rewrite directives?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Here's an excerpt from my nginx conf:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args @no-dot-php;
    autoindex on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    internal;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
}

location @no-dot-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php last;
}
```

I wanted to use an extenionless php directive and it works fine. I added `internal;` so that if you add .php to the url it will throw a 404, which works.

if the url is `https://example.com/view-task?act=view&id=2` it shows the page correctly.

Now here's my problem. Without the url parameters, the php file gets downloaded instead of being rendered. Ex: `https://example.com/manage-tasks` it will download 'manage-tasks' php file.

Adding a dummy parameter solves the problem but that would really be weird. Ex: `https://example.com/manage-tasks?dummy=1`

Can someone help me fix this please?

Comment: The term `/index.php$is_args$args` is causing the problem - remove it.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you! It did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The term /index.php$is_args$args is causing the problem - remove it.

As provided by Richard Smith